# How to pass array to Elasticsearch's NewTermsQuery in Golang?

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I want to implement the following Elasticsearch query using Golang.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "range": { "sales_start_date": { "gte": "2018-07-01T00:00:00.000Z" } }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": { "item_holder_id": [2, 7, 9] }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

My current code is the following (I am using http://github.com/olivere/elastic library).

```
query := elastic.NewBoolQuery()
query = query.Must(elastic.NewRangeQuery("sales_start_date").Gte(date).TimeZone("+09:00"))
query = query.Filter(elastic.NewTermsQuery("item_holder_id", ihids))
```

with ihids being an `[]int`. 
When I execute this code I got the error

```
elastic: Error 400 (Bad Request): [terms] unknown token [END_ARRAY] after [item_holder_id] [type=parsing_exception]
```

After some research I found out that I need to write this like this

```
elastic.NewTermsQuery("item_holder_id", "1", "2")
```

but being new to Golang I guess I am missing some of the basic concepts. How can I pass an array of values like this?

Thank you for any information that can help me!

Answer (score 8):

in order to complete the @Ullaakut answer:

```
// Convert type []int to type []interface{}

status := make([]interface{}, len(ihids))
for index, value := range ihids {
    status[index] = value
}

// Ullaakut aswer

query := elastic.NewBoolQuery()
query = query.Must(elastic.NewRangeQuery("sales_start_date").Gte(date).TimeZone("+09:00"))
query = query.Filter(elastic.NewTermsQuery("item_holder_id", status...))
```

I had the same issue and I solved on this way.

Answer (score 2):

```
    values := make([]interface{}, len(status))
    for i, v := range status {
        values[i] = v
    }
    query = query.Filter(elastic.NewTermsQuery("item_holder_id", values...))
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fix it by adding `...` after your `ihids` argument like this:

```
query := elastic.NewBoolQuery()
query = query.Must(elastic.NewRangeQuery("sales_start_date").Gte(date).TimeZone("+09:00"))
query = query.Filter(elastic.NewTermsQuery("item_holder_id", ihids...))
```

And for an explanation on how that works, this is from the [golang spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec):

> If f is variadic with final parameter type ...T, then within the
>   function the argument is equivalent to a parameter of type []T. At
>   each call of f, the argument passed to the final parameter is a new
>   slice of type []T whose successive elements are the actual arguments,
>   which all must be assignable to the type T.

Comment: I tried but I got the following error on compile.

`cannot use ihids (type []int) as type []interface {} in argument to elastic.NewTermsQuery`

I found somehow a way to fix it by looking at this blog, though I don't really understand what it does...
https://www.cnblogs.com/xdao/p/9262293.html

Comment: Well they're doing exactly what I said: `status := ToInterfaceSlice([]int{1,2})
query = query.Filter(elastic.NewTermsQuery("status",status... )`, adding `...` after the slice that is passed to split it into variadic parameters.